# Detect current img src within div

Tags: jquery, image, url, src

I have a div (id="chart") that houses many images.  How do I detect the img src within the div and assign a var to it.  Here's what I have tried so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Stopbutton').hide();

    var imgref = $('img','#chart').attr('src');

    if (imgref == 'url1'){
        $('#Loopbutton').show();
    }
    else if (imgref  == 'url2'){
        $('#Stopbutton').show();
    }
    else if (imgref != 'url3'||imgref != 'url4'){
        $('#Stopbutton').hide();
        $('#Loopbutton').hide();
    }

    //add more jquery here to keep inside the document ready function
});    




<div id="chart">      


<img id="IMG1" name="mymap" src="url1"; width=1000; height=700;"/>    

<a id="Loop" title="Loop Image">  
  <img id="Loopbutton" src="loopimage.png" width="132" height="22"></a>

  <a id="Stop" title="Stop Loop">
  <img id="Stopbutton" src="stoploop.png" width="112" height="22"></a>


<div class="basemap" id="ME_basemap" >
<img src="other url" width="1000" height="700"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: you have many images in `#chart` or just one? and you want all the `src`s from all the images, or want just one?

Comment: I have many.  They are called from separate links.

Comment: I think you can access the current image by some class or attribute added to it. Probably display will be bot none for the current image. That way you can identify the current image.

Comment: It would be better of you can add the markup of your div also.

Comment: Here is the markup for the div.  I have divs nested.  I am trying to detect the main image (#IMG1) src within the parent div id="chart".  This src could be a number of urls.  I also updated the last else if statement to include Gavin's edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to loop through each image? You would do that like this:

```
$('img','#chart').each(function(){
    $('#Stopbutton').hide();

    var imgref = $(this).attr('src');

    if (imgref == 'url1'){
        $('#Loopbutton').show();
    }
    else if (imgref  == 'url2'){
        $('#Stopbutton').show();
    }
    else if (imgref != 'url3' || imgref != 'url4'){
        $('#Stopbutton').hide();
        $('#Loopbutton').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to check the current img src in the div and show/hide loop buttons based on src url

Comment: In your code you have a problem though. On the last part you have `else if (imgref != 'url3'||'url4'){`. You cannot just have `|| 'url4'` like that. Do you mean to say `else if (imgref != 'url3'||imgref != 'url4'){`?

Answer (score 0):

var imgref = $('#chart img').attr('src');

Updated:

probably you should have the condition

```
else if (imgref != 'url3' && imgref != 'url4')
```

Comment: this is almost working.  The last 'else if' is looking for any src other than url3 or url4 to hide the buttons.  The buttons are still visible with other urls.